# Rails mailer is not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created this mailer class but this not working what could be the problem.

Getting an error:

app/mailers/interview_mailer.rb:6:in `reminder_send'
InterviewMailer#reminder_send: processed outbound mail in 3.1ms
Completed 302 Found in 156ms (ActiveRecord: 13.0ms | Allocations: 16085)

```
class InterviewMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def reminder_send(interview)
        @interview = interview
        puts(interview)
        @interview_participants = InterviewParticipant.where(interview_id: @interview.id)
        @interview_participants.each do |interview_participant|
            @participant = Participant.find(interview_participant.participant_id)
            mail to: participant.email, subject: "Your interview is updated", from: 'abc@gmail.com'

        end

    end
end
```

Comment: Are you calling it in a controller?  Do you have `perform_deliveries` set to true in your current environment file?  Check out:  `domain/rails/mailers` for development do `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers`.  Does your mailer appear? (You have to set up test file)

Comment: @tblev Yes, I calling it in controller

Comment: @tblev I could not found this: `domain/rails/mailers`

Comment: @tblev In `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers` I see `Interview Mailer` and I click it. I see a text `Interview Mailer`

Comment: I was just meaning domain as in like wherever you're navigating to.  Say you had your site deployed already.  Though if you see your text inside of itnerview mailer (the text in your mailer view) then that works, post your controller code and also, make sure your ` config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries` is set to true in `config/environments/development.rb`.  If that doesn't work, then it's probably in your smtp settings.

Comment: First off, you should take loop out and place in controller. You need to pass each participant to mailer to send out mail to each participant. Share your controller code which calls the mailer.

Comment: You should use ".pluck". It is possible to send email to one or more recipients in one email (e.g., informing all admins of a new signup) by setting the list of emails to the :to key. The list of emails can be an array of email addresses or a single string with the addresses separated by commas. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-to-multiple-recipients